# Angular: Component X is not included in a module and will not be available inside a template

Tags: angular, webstorm, tslint

In my Angular application, I have few components which are used while testing and not included in any module.

In WebStorm, it shows me a lint error saying `Component is not included in any module`, while I know that this is not included and that is the purpose.

Is there a way to disable only this lint error while keeping all others enabled?

> Angular: Component 'ComponentName' is not included in a module and
>   will not be available inside a template. Consider adding it to a
>   NgModule declaration.

I saw [this threat](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000143590-Angular-2-4-wrong-inspection-Component-is-not-included-in-a-module-?flash_digest=8508fdac8104b1ee0641efa61a67665260a116ac), where it was suggested to disable all Angular lint errors. However, i think it is not a good idea to do that just for one issue. I am looking for a way to only disable this one error.

Comment: I also met this error which prevents me from running the UT, appreciates it if you can share your solutions if the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me:

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart

Comment: I think this one worked for me. I will validate little more and confirm you @Filip

Answer (score 3):

Angular language service doesn't provide a possibility to suppress particular rules/checks. Please follow https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13726 for updates

Comment: Running `npm install @angular/language-service` and restarting IDE, resolved the problem. `@angular/language-service` updated to version 5.2.0

Comment: Why it does not do automatically. Why we have to install an extra thing to get only that in IDE?

Answer (score 3):

I use **PHPStorm** and found this problem also when using Angular 4. I fixed it by `npm install @angular/language-service`.

Comment: Had the same issue with *visual studio code*. And the same solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

On Webstorm you can just press `Alt+Enter` and it will display a list, where you can choose `disable inspection`, and it will update rules of inspection automatically to all same cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following comment above the class declaration and it will skip the check for that class:

```
// noinspection AngularMissingOrInvalidDeclarationInModule
```

You can also get the editor to add that comment for you by using the contextual menu you get when you hover over the error and going to 'Inspection options > Suppress for statement'